# How to retrieve GPS location from videos captured by iOS devices using Swift?

Tags: swift, gps, avfoundation, metadata, avasset

I have been trying to extract GPS metadata from video captured by iphone. The following code produces the following result:

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
let allFormats = asset.availableMetadataFormats
allFormats.forEach {
    let metadataItems = asset.metadata(forFormat: $0)
    metadataItems.forEach {
        print("key: \($0.key!)")
        print("data: \($0.value!)")
        print("---------")
    }
}
```

Result is:

```
key: com.apple.quicktime.make
data: Apple
---------
key: com.apple.quicktime.model
data: iPhone 7
---------
key: com.apple.quicktime.software
data: 13.3
---------
key: com.apple.quicktime.creationdate
data: 2019-12-03T16:10:08+0300
---------
```

It means for me that AVFoundation gives only poor metadata information. But how to get GPS metadata? I know that captured videos contain geotags because exiftool extracts GPS metadata. Similar questions have already been raised here. But I could not find the answers on the merits.